# How old a Mac can be upgraded with OS X Server to provide full Time Machine Server to Mojave?

Tags: time-machine, osx-server, time-capsule

I have been a faithful customer of Time Capsules for the last 10 years as I have found them to be the perfect accessory to a laptop, but now Apple has discontinued the product and essentially refers to "use another mac as destination".

Today this is in Mojave, but previously it was in OS X Server.  As I have my previous Mac's lying around still, I was wondering if it would be a reasonable path to upgrade the harddisk to some terrabytes and purchase OS X Server for that elderly machine (10.7 for one and 10.11 for the other).

Does that make sense or has some new facilites been added since, that makes this a bad idea? I would like full functionality, including being able to restore from it as part of setting up a new Mac.

Comment: Can you specify the make and models of the older Macs that you have? It will help in determining the version of the latest macOS they are capable of running.

Comment: Sure.  White macbook 2008 capable of running 10.7, and MacBook Pro 2009 capable of running 10.11 if I recall correctly.